# How to enable/configure zswap on Debian (Azure)

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

The

**Higher Performance with ZSWAP**
https://medium.com/for-linux-users/linux-tip-higher-performance-with-zswap-2a4654b935de

interests me, but my situation is,

```sh
$ cat /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled
cat: /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled: No such file or directory
```

to which the article says,

> If you get some sort of file not found error, then your kernel doesn’t have the code needed for zswap. You can try installing a different kernel, or — if you are really motivated — build your own kernel.

The problem is,

- I'm using the latest brand new Debian on Azure.
- I don't want to build my own kernel, and
- the likelihood of installing a different kernel on Azure is rather slim.

Looks like [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-zswap-on-linux/) is an alternative, but such simple solution contradicts the conclusion from the above article that I need to build my own kernel.

Any one get ZSWAP properly configured on (Azure) Debian?

Comment: If you can't use zswap, you can consider zram instead which is available as module in the cloud flavor. Or you could install the non-cloud version of the Debian kernel (which still has hyper-v options) which has zswap available.

Comment: Maybe that's the best option I can have. thx.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution how to enable *zswap* in Ubuntu within WSL2 on Windows 11.

Comment: @bjmi WSL2 is not Azure... you should ask your own question. And considering this is a **kernel** feature and the kernel is provided by Microsoft and not Debian...

Comment: @xpt about Azure it's about the kernel. The Debian -cloud flavor of the kernel doesn't have zswap enabled. What is the kernel in use in Azure? Debian's cloud? Debian's normal? or a custom Azure kernel?

Comment: @A.B Thanks for "this is a kernel feature and the kernel is provided by Microsoft and not Debian...". This information helps where I can look further.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @A.B, I didn't know how to choose Debian kernel for Azure then, and I lost access to it (Azure) not long after.